# how to get value form 2nd table with out join in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

hi i have a table called CHECKPRODUCT.

i also has 2nd table called CHECKSTATUS_LOOKUP with column name DESCRIPTION

while i am getting values from CHECKPRODUCT, i also want value from DESCRIPTION column of 2nd table(CHECKSTATUS_LOOKUP) but i dont want ot join both tables. is there any ways to do that

Comment: As Fabio already mentioned, it would be useful to talk about classes, their fields and their relations. How are those two classes/tables related. Does CheckProduct have a getter for CheckStatus? Is this a to-one or to-many relation?
And what do you mean by getting the value from the second table without joining both tables? So are they related in any way?

Comment: BTW why you want to avoid the `join`?

Answer (score 1):

Please give more details and explain what columns you have in the two tables and what exactly is the requirement.

You could use a subquery instead of a join in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Only an advise. When you are using Hibernate or NHibernate is better to talk about class+properties instead table+fields